# How to join multiple tables?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, lambda, code-first

I have the following classes. I have a object `var` of Description class. I want to select Balance related to the Client provided in the `var` object using Linq to Sql or Lambda expression. How to join these tables to get the Balance from Account table?

```
public class Description
    {
        public int DescriptionID { get; set; }

       // Attributes

        public int ClientID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ClientID")]
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }


    }

public class Client
    {
        public int ClientID { get; set; }

       // Attributes

        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserID")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

    }

 public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }

       // Attributes

     }

 public class Account
    {

        public int AccountID { get; set; }

        [Required, Column("Balance"), Display(Name = "Account Balance")]
        public double Balance { get; set; }


        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserID")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framework-join-3-tables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Join 3 Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051612/entity-framework-join-3-tables)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var balance = (from a in context.Accounts
               join c in context.Clients on a.UserID equals c.UserID
               where c.ClientID == yourDescriptionObject.ClientID
               select a.Balance)
              .SingleOrDefault();
```

Or - if you only have the `DescriptionID`:

```
var balance = (from a in context.Accounts
               join c in context.Clients on a.UserID equals c.UserID
               join d in context.Descriptions on c.ClientID equals d.ClientID
               where d.DescriptionID == yourDescriptionID
               select a.Balance)
              .SingleOrDefault();
```

(Or `FirstOrDefault()` or `ToList()` or `Sum()`? Because your model would allow that clients/descriptions are related to multiple accounts ...)